# Is it safe and practical to visit the Northern Territory?

Tags: safety, australia, event-based-effects, northern-territory

After watching "Australia" by Baz Luhmann and following the NT News on Twitter, I'm thinking of visiting the Northern Territory.

However, I've heard about flooding in the NT and I'm wondering whether it's a good idea to do so in the next couple of days.

I tried looking at smartraveller.gov.au but it doesn't provide travel advice for Australia itself, and the UK equivalent didn't seem to post any updates for the recent flooding - the most recent update concerned a change to the terrorism threat level.

Is there somewhere in the NT accessible by flight from Sydney, preferably Darwin, that is not affected by flooding, unable to accomodate tourists due to evacuees, or impractical to enjoy due to persistent bad weather?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TL;DR: **Yes**.

The Northern Territory is *huge*, and spans a range of climates from sopping-wet tropical to bone-dry desert.  The [current floods](http://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/2015/dec/28/woman-dies-floodwaters-force-hundreds-evacuate-across-northern-territory) (Dec 2015) are primarily around the Daly River/Waters region, several hundred kilometers south of Darwin, and both Darwin itself and the tourist hubs of Alice Springs and Uluru (Ayers Rock), over 1000 km to the south, are entirely unaffected.  All three have direct flights from Sydney.

All that said, it's [The Wet](http://www.travelnt.com/travelling-in-the-nt/weather-and-seasons) right now in NT, meaning the tropical bits get a *lot* of rain even when it's not outright flooding. Down at Uluru though, it's summer and thus very dry and hot.

Comment: Isn't *now* summer in the Southern Hemisphere?

Comment: It is still early summer, like June in the Northern Hemisphere. It will get hotter later in the summer.

Comment: @Willele Gah, brainfart, fixed (and I'm *in* Australia as I write this...!).

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

This photo is from today, as can be verified by the copy of the NT News I'm holding, and in the background is the mostly dry Todd River.

[image]